# CSS selectors for dynamic generated divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, web-scraping

I'm using webscraper.io.

I'm trying to target a series of blog post wrappers to scrape the code within, loop and repeat to the next one, however:

- I can't get the UI to work
- The site is using dynamic code which is hard to target

I think I need to do this manually with attribute selectors to target all posts and cut out the generated numbers

**Here is the first lot of code I want to target which are public posts**

```
<div data-id="urn:li:activity:6523656250994102272" id="ember2615" class="relative ember-view">
<div data-id="urn:li:activity:6468819859034685441" id="ember2669" class="relative ember-view">
<div data-id="urn:li:activity:6523656352009719808" id="ember2674" class="relative ember-view">
<div data-id="urn:li:activity:6523656467717980160" id="ember2679" class="relative ember-view">
```

I tried this but I couldn't get it to work

```
div[data-id^="urn"][class$="ember-view"]
```

**Here is the second lot of code I want to target**

```
<div id="ember1222" class="ember-view">
<div id="ember1271" class="ember-view">
<div id="ember1322" class="ember-view">
<div id="ember1371" class="ember-view">
<div id="ember1420" class="ember-view">
<div id="ember1471" class="ember-view">
```

I tried this but I couldn't get it to work

```
div[id^="ember"][class$="ember-view"]
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mp0wbknj/  works fine.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mp0wbknj/1/  also works fine.

Comment: What does _doesn't work_ mean?